# Disable Second Textbox

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a jQuery script (below) which works as shown: http://jsfiddle.net/rLT3b/1/

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
if(this.checked == true) {
    $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').val("1").removeAttr("disabled"); }
else {
    $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').val("0").attr("disabled", "disabled"); }
});
```

How can this be altered to also disable the first textbox in the example?  So when it is unchecked, both textboxes are disabled, and then both are enabled if it is checked again.

Comment: pretty difficult to answer this question if you don't post your html.

Comment: @reilg The html is in the jsfiddle link :p

Comment: What's the purpose of `.val('0')` and `.val('1')`?  Is this specific to the second input only?

Comment: lol. I didn't even notice the fiddle link. Don't mind me then. Heh. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traverse a step higher up the DOM, then find the text inputs and toggle the 'disabled' property:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rLT3b/7/)

**Note:** It is faster to use `[type="text"]` or `[type="checkbox"]` than to use `:text` or `:checkbox`, as the former take advantage of native CSS selectors.  [See performance test](http://jsperf.com/disable-texboxes).

Answer (score 4):

You could targetting tr instead of td:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rLT3b/3/)

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
if(this.checked == true) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:not(:checkbox)').prop('disabled',false); }
else {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:not(:checkbox)').prop('disabled',true); }
});
```

Comment: Ah thanks roasted!  This makes a lot more sense the functionality of my page!  Much appreciated!